# How to get only solved tickets using Zendesk v2 API

Tags: c#, zendesk-api

I have been looking for hours now, however I cannot find a simple way (or any way) to get a ticket by ID or tickets by tag.

Currently, because I cannot find the above, I am checking each ticket individually to see if its solved. There must be a better way.

Please let me know if there is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use search API

[Reference](https://developer.zendesk.com/rest_api/docs/core/search)

You have to Hit Below Endpoint

> .../api/v2/search.json?query={search_string}

And you have to use below query

> query=type:ticket status:open Open tickets

Comment: For some one in future :

var totalSolvedTickets = api.Search.SearchFor<Ticket>("status:solved");